# Getting object value

Tags: php, api

I use third-party API retrieving business information. The object looks somewhat like this:

```
[businesses] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (                    
                [name] => Business Name                    
                [location] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [city] => Dallas
                        [display_address] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 123 Yellow Rd 620 N
```

To get business name I do:

```
$name = $response->businesses[0]->name;
```

I'm trying to get city and address now.

```
$name = $response->businesses[0]['location']->city;
```

Doesn't seem to work... What am I missing?

Comment: API isn't a language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below - location is an Object, so you should be able to reference it with -> notation.

```
$city = $response->businesses[0]->location->city;
```

display_address

```
$display_address = $response->businesses[0]->location->display_address[0];
```

Comment: Dah... Long day... Thanks!